# Alternative for SQL Between for Non numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have non numeric values in one of my column. I am using between operator as below but I think for non numeric values between operator is not recommended, could someone suggest how I can rewrite this query. BETWEEN is showing correct results but I cannot use it for non numeric values here:

```
select * from test
where textnumber between ('a64') AND ('a64.3');
```

Comment: What values do you want to get by this query?

Comment: what about stripping off the letter in the where clause and adding it back in in the select. is it always one character letter?

Comment: I wanted to get a64 which works using BETWEEN operator as backend SQL but Its not working for logic I have in code. Whats the other way without using BETWEEN operator here. Also I don't want to create any temp table for thsi purpose.

Comment: [What is not working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fec70/1)? Could you elaborate?

Comment: i just ran this query and it is working fine.  The only time it would not if you looking for a value like a64.22 and consider that between

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE textnumber >= 'a64' AND textnumber < 'a64.4';`? If not, please tell us what not working means and show us sample data and desired results. What values are you trying to pick up but cannot?

Comment: @ObieMD5 I think you meant some value other than `a64.22` - that specific value certainly matches the `WHERE` clause above (while `a64.30` would not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always break up a `BETWEEN` into it's component parts.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE textnumber >= 'a64'
  AND textnumber <= 'a64.3';
```

In fact if you read Aaron Bertrand's blog [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) you will see that he in fact recommends it.  Particularly for dates, although that isn't what you are working with.

Also be warned that strings and numbers are NOT the same.  For example `'a64.30'` will `NOT` be picked up by the above query.